# I wonder if the value changes depending on whether or not a list is applied to the map

Tags: python-3.x

```
re = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
result = []
a=list(map(lambda n:result.append(n), [i for i in re if i>5]))
print(result)
print(a)
```

If you run the above code, the value of result comes out correctly

```
re = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
result = []
a=list(map(lambda n:result.append(n), [i for i in re if i>5]))
print(result)
print(a)
```

The value of the result changes depending on whether the list is wrapped in a map or not, but I wonder why.

I expected a value to be added to result, but it is not added unless I wrap it in a list.

Comment: note `re` is the name of the regex module so I would discourage that name for a variable.

Comment: It is very anti-Pythonic to do  this style of coding by using *side-effect*! Avoid it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map()` is a generator and is not processed until exercised.  Try:

```py
re = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
result = []
map_result = map(lambda n:result.append(n), [i for i in re if i>5])
print(result)
next(map_result)
print(result)
```

You will see that getting the first result from the mapping via `next()` has begun to populate the list `result`. You can call `next(a)` again and see that `result` would then have two items and so on...

When you call `list()` on a generator, you get "all the results" from it and exhaust it.  Thus calling `list()` populates `result` with the three items.

Note that `append()` does not return a value (implied return of `None`) and thus the variable `a` in your code will be `[None, None, None]`.

This use of `map()` is not pythonic and calling map for side effects should be avoided for the same reasons that comprehensions for side effects should be avoided.

See Also: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)